# How to convert a vector including number and character into numeric vector in python?

Tags: python

Is there anyway to do this without using forloop?

Input: `c("1","2","3","a")`

Expected output: `'c(1,2,3,NA)`

I am not familiar with python, so I use the format of R to describe the input and output.

Comment: You can use `split(',')` and `map()`

Comment: Sorry, I am new to python and still not familiar with the vector format of python. I mean these are the elements of vector

Comment: What output do you expect for `'1.2'`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
from math import nan

lst = ["1","2","3","a"]



lst = [int(a) if a.isdigit() else nan for a in lst]


print(lst)
```

output

```
[1, 2, 3, nan]
```

Comment: So it is different from R, python can't use built-in function (e.g. function like as.numeric from R) to do the thing I mentioned in the question? Thanks for your help!